# NSIS Erroring out when being run from Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, nsis

I have a PowerShell script that builds an NSIS installer. It works great if I run it directly on a system. When I add it to my Jenkins pipeline, I get the following error:

```
Internal compiler error #12345
```

I know all about the 2GB size limitation; the file it's choking on is only 52MB... besides the script runs great outside of Jenkins.

I've tried adding some sleeps, deleting all or part of the Jenkins workspace (occasionally the installer will compile if there's no workspace).

Anyone have any ideas? I'm kinda stumped.

EDIT: Here's the PowerShell call and the lines of source that blow up:

```
Write-Output "Compiling installer"
$relmod = $deployXML.'deploy-bundler'.relmod
$cmd = '& ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\NSIS\makensis .\deploy-bundler\install\win32\installer-pieces\bundle.nsi -DRELMOD=$relmod'
invoke-expression $cmd
```

Here's the NSIS:

```
Section /o "${PRODUCT_IBMI}" SECSoftware
  SectionIn 1
  SetOutPath "$TEMP\${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PATH}$uniquePath"
  SetDetailsView hide
  ; The following lines modify the text display in the progress banner
  GetDlgItem $R0 $HWNDPARENT 1037
  SendMessage $R0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "${PROGRESS_BANNER_BOLD_TEXT}" 
  GetDlgItem $R0 $HWNDPARENT 1038
  SendMessage $R0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "${PROGRESS_BANNER_TEXT}" 

  File "deliverables\${PRODUCT_FILE}"
```

Comment: NSIS version? Minimal code sample?

Comment: NSIS 2.50… I'll work on posting a minimal code sample tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as it turns out was a copy-paste error. In the Jenkins config, I had a withEnv closure. In that closure, it was pointing TMP to the D: drive. The D: drive doesn't exist on the system and when NSIS had to go to the file system to create temp files, there was no space, hence the error.

For anyone searching for NSIS Internal compiler error #12345, one of the causes can be a lack of disk space, which was the case here.

Comment: The disk problem applies to "Internal compiler error #12345: error creating mmap the size of ...", other mmap errors might be memory based.